# Convergence of Monotone sequences? example

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

An example of an unbounded increasing sequence that satisfies the assumptions of the convergence of monotone sequences...?

According to the convergence of monotone sequences if a sequences is monotonic and bounded then it converges to some $L$.

I think $S(n)=n+1$ since it's increasing and it's unbounded 
correct?

Comment: Your approach is correct.

Comment: Yes, it is a counter-example if you remove the bounded condition.

Comment: oh ok i see thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your example $a_n = n$ satisfies that it is monotone but not bounded, and is therefore not necessarily convergent. For an example that is bounded but not monotone, just take the sequence $-1, 1, -1, 1, \ldots$. Any convergent sequence must be bounded. But not every convergent sequence must be monotone. Just take $a_n = (-1)^n/n$.

Comment: is there a sequence which is unbounded and monotone that converges?

Comment: No; if we have some monotone sequence $\{a_n\}$ with limit $L$, then letting $\epsilon = |a_0 - L|$ implies that $|a_n - L| < \epsilon$ for every $n$. But like @user2566092 said, convergent sequences are always bounded whether they're monotone or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you are asking!  You say "An example of an unbounded increasing sequence that satisfies the assumptions of the convergence of monotone sequences".   One of the **assumptions** is that the sequence be bounded!